# Amazon EC2 elastic-IP problems

Tags: amazon-ec2

Has anyone experienced your elastic IP going bananas?

I set up an elastic IP and it just went crazy so my instance was unavailable, in the end I had to terminate it...

I couldn't get hold of any logs och reports, feels very very strange...

Thanks!

Comment: You have not provided enough details on the problem you are seeing for anybody to help.  Describe what you are trying to do, and list the exact symptoms and results that you receive.

Answer (score 6):

An EIP (Elastic IP) address is nothing more than a reserved address which is assigned to your EC2 account, and which you can allocate to any running VM you own.

There isn't anything to 'go crazy' with an EIP, since it is an inert object - when not assigned to a VM it does nothing but cost you a tiny amount of money, and, when assigned, its' cost drops to zero and the VM switches its' default address out and assumes the EIP instead.

Comment: That's what I thought, but for some reason my instance went down! From the tiny amount of information I was able to obtain it seems the ip was responsible...I'll se if I can provide som info...

Comment: @Siddharth Sorry, but that's got to be a local issue to you - user error or just plain bad luck. I've been using EIPs extensively for three years and *never once* experienced either a 'failure', 'hang', or (as in the case of OP) an entire instance rendered unusable.

Answer (score 2):

The IP cannot go "bananas". Look the AWS console for the public DNS of the server. Try connecting using that instead of the elastic IP. If connecting using that fails then it is the instance itself that is that problem.

If that works, then how long did you leave between attaching the IP and trying to connect (i.e. what are the timescales on this problem)?

Comment: The thing is, I have been able to log without any problems, then my instance just went down and from the tiny bit of information I was able to obtain all signs point to the elastic IP :S

Comment: This is an engineering discussion, "going bananas" is not an engineering term to use. In the vast majority of cases, users simply have not configured their security group correctly. I'm happy to discuss this rationally, rather than throw around terms that imply things without evidence to back it up.

Comment: @David Please note that Siddharth and the OP are not the same person - for some reason Siddharth has associated a new ServerFault question s/he asked today with this (much) older SO question and is muddying answers with spurious comments and downvotes.